# Rails 4: Ember.js doesn't see my templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to just render a template from `templates/about.handlebars`.

I have the outlet setup in rails view:

```
%script{ type: 'text/x-handlebars'}
  <h1> My app</h1>
  {{ outlet }}
  ^-- outlet
```

the about route looks like this:

```
Admin.Router.map ->
  @route 'about', path: '/'
```

And the about template is plain html:

```
<h1>This is ABOUT!</h1>
```

What seems to work:

- I can see the Ember debug message, that confirms ember is working
- I have ember chrome extension installed and it can see the application template

But, when I ask for `Ember.TEMPLATES`, I get:

```
Object {application: function} 
application: function (context, options) { 
__proto__: Object
```

and no about template there.

Digging in the compiled js file, I can see the handlebar template is physically there:

```
(function() {
  this.HandlebarsTemplates || (this.HandlebarsTemplates = {});
  this.HandlebarsTemplates["about"] = Handlebars.template(function (Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
  this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};



  return "\n<h1>This is ABOUT!</h1>\n\n";
  });
  return this.HandlebarsTemplates["about"];
}).call(this);
```

But I don't see it being explicitly added to Ember.TEMPLATES.

**Update 1:** Inspecting the ember-rails gem, I see that handlebars [will match only files that have `.raw.(hjs|...)`, or `mustache.(hjs|...)` in their names](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/blob/master/lib/ember/handlebars/template.rb#L51)? Documentation doesn't seem to speak about this.

Even if I rename the template it still doesn't show and its supper weird since I haven't seen templates names like that in tutorials, or the gem documentation.

Comment: That code in Update 1 means that, if you have a file called `someFile.raw.(handlebars|hjs|hbs)`, ember-rails will use `Handlebars.compiler` instead of `Ember.Handlebars.compiler`. The Ember.Handlebars.compiler is a extension of Handlebars.compiler that allow the usage of computed properties, bindings, etc in handlebars templates. And probally this is what you will use. So use your templates files without the `raw` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Ember looks for precompiled templates in Ember.TEMPLATES, not HandlebarsTemplates.

Comment: Handlebars are 1.0.12. If I read the ember-rails gem correctly, the ember-rails gem is responsible for plugging them in.